Are Jewish and non-Jewish souls equal?
I have two questions. 1. Are Jews and non-Jews born with the same number of souls and are both able to be equal in the eyes of Hashem? 2. Can the non-Jewish soul ever be equal to the soul of a Jew?

Thanks for the question. I VTC because it needs more detail and clarity. What do you mean by equal? What makes you think we have "multiple souls"?

For R Yehudah Halevi only a native jew can access nevuah whereas for Rambam who defines the immortal soul as the intellect it is presumably egalitarian

@Danny please work that into the question rather than leaving as a comment and don't forget to define equal

@Nahum we had non-Jewish prophets. Moshiach is also from the line of Ruth the convert. Some of our greatest sages were also converts (although they divine insight and not prophecy)

@RabbiKaii 1. I often hear Rabbis say that Jews have a higher soul than non-jews because of their unique purpose and 2. Jews would often get an extra soul to complete certain mitzvot or on Shabbat this is different from non-Jews.

That question has been asked of the kuzari, I'm just reporting

All living things have a soul, but according to Tanya, Jews have an additional G-dly soul with a higher spiritual source.

The essence of your question is related to Bereshit 1:24-27 and Bereshit 2:7 which say the following:

וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֗ים תּוֹצֵ֨א הָאָ֜רֶץ נֶ֤פֶשׁ חַיָּה֙ לְמִינָ֔הּ בְּהֵמָ֥ה וָרֶ֛מֶשׂ וְחַֽיְתוֹ־אֶ֖רֶץ לְמִינָ֑הּ וַֽיְהִי־כֵֽן׃
וַיַּ֣עַשׂ אֱלֹהִים֩ אֶת־חַיַּ֨ת הָאָ֜רֶץ לְמִינָ֗הּ וְאֶת־הַבְּהֵמָה֙ לְמִינָ֔הּ וְאֵ֛ת כׇּל־רֶ֥מֶשׂ הָֽאֲדָמָ֖ה לְמִינֵ֑הוּ וַיַּ֥רְא אֱלֹהִ֖ים כִּי־טֽוֹב׃
וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֔ים נַֽעֲשֶׂ֥ה אָדָ֛ם בְּצַלְמֵ֖נוּ כִּדְמוּתֵ֑נוּ וְיִרְדּוּ֩ בִדְגַ֨ת הַיָּ֜ם וּבְע֣וֹף הַשָּׁמַ֗יִם וּבַבְּהֵמָה֙ וּבְכׇל־הָאָ֔רֶץ וּבְכׇל־הָרֶ֖מֶשׂ הָֽרֹמֵ֥שׂ עַל־הָאָֽרֶץ׃
וַיִּבְרָ֨א אֱלֹהִ֤ים ׀ אֶת־הָֽאָדָם֙ בְּצַלְמ֔וֹ בְּצֶ֥לֶם אֱלֹהִ֖ים בָּרָ֣א אֹת֑וֹ זָכָ֥ר וּנְקֵבָ֖ה בָּרָ֥א אֹתָֽם׃
וַיִּ֩יצֶר֩ יְהֹוָ֨ה אֱלֹהִ֜ים אֶת־הָֽאָדָ֗ם עָפָר֙ מִן־הָ֣אֲדָמָ֔ה וַיִּפַּ֥ח בְּאַפָּ֖יו נִשְׁמַ֣ת חַיִּ֑ים וַיְהִ֥י הָֽאָדָ֖ם לְנֶ֥פֶשׁ חַיָּֽה׃

That the souls of non-Jews originate from the earth.
The Jewish soul originates from G-d's breath, so to speak. Like the sentence emphasizes, G-d blew (forcefully) from His innermost essence into the nostrils of the Jewish body that He had formed from the earth.
They are not the same. The non-Jewish soul originates from what is described as the external aspect of Creation. The Jewish soul originates from the internal aspect.
Allegorically speaking, think of  it as the difference between the surface of your skin in contrast to your heart or lungs inside  of your body.
Regarding how G-d views this, the Torah teaches that because G-d doesn't change, meaning both before, during and after creation, (like it states in the Prophecy of Malachi 3:6 כִּ֛י אֲנִ֥י יְהוָ֖ה לֹ֣א שָׁנִ֑יתִי וְאַתֶּ֥ם בְּנֵֽי־יַעֲקֹ֖ב לֹ֥א כְלִיתֶֽם׃
) then from a certain sense, there is no difference from G-d's perspective.
Like is mentioned in the comments to your question, The Jew has an additional element or soul that does not exist with the  non-Jew. In the Tanya, this is described as the G-dly soul. The common soul aspect which is with both is the Animating (or some call it the Animal) soul.
